# How to save comment entered in textview to the map current location in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary

i have a map application in  which there are 3 buttons picture,video and comment.when a user clicks on the picture button that opens up camera for taking pictures and same is with video ,he can take video .this 2 buttons are done.when the user clicks on the third comment button a comment page opens where he can enter the comment title and enter comment and when he clicks on the submit button the comment the user has entered will be posted to his current location.Please can anybody help me in solving this problem on how to save comment to current location on map.thanks

Comment: What is your problem? How to get user's current location? Or how to display it on a map?

Comment: How to display comment entered in textview on user's current location

Comment: Do you want [such view](http://goo.gl/cltYJ), but instead of "Blue Chillies" you want place user's comment?

Comment: in the view you have shown when blue chillies is clicked an image is shown but when i click on the annotation i want the comments posted by user at that location to be visible.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotation view is too small to showing entire comment. Usually such things done like:

1) User touch pin
2) Annotation view showing with some text (for you, as exmaple, part of comment) and detail disclosure button
3) When user click on detail disclosure button new view controller with entire comment pushed.

Comment: Tell me what you can't understand. What point of my answer you can't implement (1, 2 or 3)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your own MKAnnotation to display points on the map (rather than MKPlacemark, etc.), you should be able to do something like the following:

```
currentAnnotation.title = textView.text;
```

Just be sure to add

```
- (NSString *)title {
    return title;
}
```

and

```
@synthesize title;
```

to your custom MKAnnotation class implementation file as well as

```
NSString *title;
```

and

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
```

to the custom MKAnnotation header file

I'm not sure if it will update the field immediately or if you will need to remove and add your annotation to the map again.  Usually you give it a title when you create the annotation, so if you are adding a title later on (when the annotation is present on the map), it may not update without you forcing it to.  I hope this helps